# How can i read datas on sqlite3 with php variables?

Tags: pdo, sqlite

```
$result = $vt->prepare('SELECT * FROM streamdetails WHERE idFile ='.$idFile.' AND iStreamType =0');
$result->execute();
foreach($result as $row)
    echo "Çözünürlük: ".$row['iVideoWidth'] . " x " .$row['iVideoHeight'] . "<br>";
}
```

What is wrong?

$idFile variable type is text but idFile is integer on streamdetails.

Comment: You should always use `$vt->escapeString($variable)` in your queries.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: For example your `$idFile` variable. If it was a user input, it could be anything, including an SQL request. To prevent this kind of problem, you have to use the SQLite3 method `escapeString()` or (in this case), if you want a number, you can use `intVal()`. In this case, even if the user attempted an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), your app is protected.

However to help you more I'd need the error message you get.